# how to SVG sprite in ionic angular project?

Tags: angular, ionic4

How can I use SVG Sprite in ionic angular project?  I am using https://github.com/jannicz/ng-svg-icon-sprite this but [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vwLk.png)

I am getting this error ?

Answer (score 0):

Evenutally use a tested npm-module;

```
$ npm i angular-svg-icon --save
```

---

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularSvgIconModule } from 'angular-svg-icon';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ HttpClientModule, AngularSvgIconModule ],
  ...
})
```

export class AppModule {}

---

```
< svg-icon src="images/eye.svg" [svgStyle]="{ 'width.px':90 }" ></svg-icon>
```

Test it !